# How can I make a functioning animated button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a button set up in a scene like this:

```
self.playButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithImageNamed:@"playbutton.png"];
self.playButton.size = CGSizeMake(100,100);
self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 100);
[self addChild:self.playButton];
```

Then in touchesBegan:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

if([self.playButton containsPoint:location]){
    self.playButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"playbuttonpressed.png"];
    [self.playButton runAction: [self touchButtonAction]];
}
```

Then in touchesEnded:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

if([self.playButton containsPoint:location]){
    self.playButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"playbutton.png"];
    [self.view presentScene:self.nextScene transition:self.sceneTransition];

}
```

Then in touchButtonAction:

```
SKAction *toSmall = [SKAction scaleBy:0.8 duration:0.1];
return toSmall;
```

**Here's the problem:** When I tap the button, touchesEnded gets called before the action is finished, which causes for an incomplete animation which doesn't look good (it seems laggy). How can I make a button that finishes the animation before transitioning?

Comment: Try Out AGSpriteButton. It implements the same animation by default.
https://github.com/akashgupta88/AGSpriteButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of accomplishing what you want. One of those is using blocks.

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

if([self.playButton containsPoint:location]){

    SKAction *block0 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        self.playButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"playbuttonpressed.png"];
        [self.playButton runAction: [self touchButtonAction]];
    }];

    SKAction *wait0 = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0]; // <- however long it takes for the animation to complete

    SKAction *block1 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        self.playButton.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"playbutton.png"];
        [self.view presentScene:self.nextScene transaction:self.sceneTransaction];
    }];

    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[block0, wait0, block1]]];
}
```

For more information on using blocks, you can read the [Apple Blocks Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks! Once again you have helped me a lot. The game should be out shortly (if apple agrees)